# Convert BigInt timestamp to just Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-conversion

I am facing a problem in conversion and type cast. I've a field which is of Data Type BigInt that has a value stored in the format "yyyymmddhhmmss" like "20170609043000". I am trying to get the substring of date part in the timestamp like 20170609 with a separator as 2017-06-09. Not able to fetch the date part in the timestamp.

Query I tried to fetch the Date part:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate,15) as varchar),1, 5), 102) from Event evt

SELECT DATEADD(hour,-5, CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar),6, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 8, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 1,5) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar),10, 2) + ':' +SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 14, 2), 120)) from Event evt
```

The first query returns the converted date but the month and date remains same , concatenation doesn't work if I try to substring month and date.

Second query doesn't work at all.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Note that a `DATETIME2(0)` takes only 6 bytes (as opposed to `BIGINT`s 8) so even storage requirements aren't a valid concern for using this approach, which complicates almost every operation save for simple comparisons. `CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(20170609043000, 5, 0, '-'), 8, 0, '-'), 11, 0, 'T'), 14, 0, ':'), 17, 0, ':'))` is one way to perform that conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just take the 8 left most characters, and convert it?

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, LEFT(20170609043000,8));
```

Ideally though, you should be using a date and time datatype to store your date and time data. Storing them in a different data type only ends up causing problems and never solves a problem that can't be solved else where (aka your presentation layer).

Answer (score 1):

Your second query is almost right but is getting the year, month, date in the wrong order. Try this instead:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar),2, 4) + '-' + 
                         SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 6, 2) + '-' + 
                         SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 8,2) + ' ' + 
                         SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar),10, 2) + ':' + 
                         SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 12, 2) + ':' + 
                         SUBSTRING(CAST(STR(evt.StartDate, 15) as varchar), 14, 2), 120) 
FROM Event evt
```

Output:

```
09/06/2017 04:30:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=58b0f334f800f79a8256f4637d0179e2)

Comment: I don't need the time part just date yyyy-mm-dd and my timestamp is of bigInt data type.